# Ansible script module - Control socket permission denied

Tags: ansible

I'm new to Ansible and trying to run a local script on a remote node using the script module. My task is defined as follows:

```
- name: Initial setup
  script:  ../../../initial_setup.sh
  become: yes
```

When I run the playbook I get the error below but I'm not clear on what the actual problem is. Does this indicate a problem connecting to the node or a problem transferring the script?

```
fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": true,
    "failed": true,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "../../../initial_setup.sh"
        },
        "module_name": "script"
    },
    "rc": 127,
    "stderr": "Control socket connect(/tmp): Permission denied\r\nControlSocket /tmp already exists, disabling multiplexing\r\nConnection to 127.0.0.1 closed.\r\n",
    "stdout": "/bin/sh: 1: /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1482161914.64-107588947758469/initial_setup.sh: not found\r\n",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "/bin/sh: 1: /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1482161914.64-107588947758469/initial_setup.sh: not found"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you check if any other module works? For example: `shell: echo Hello`

Comment: Are you sure that `default` is a remote host?

Comment: I'm sure `default` is a remote host as it works with other tasks.

Comment: Can you change `-o ControlMaster=auto` to `-o ControlMaster=no` to `ssh_args` in the `ssh_connection` of your `ansible.cfg`? Or add the latter, if it's not defined.

Comment: Alternatively, if the above does not change change anything can you add `scp_if_ssh = True` to the `ssh_connection` section and check the result?

Comment: @tecraf thanks, adding `-o ControlMaster=auto` got rid of the permission error, I was still getting 'not found' but this turned out to be an error within my script. If you add an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr

Ensure `-o ControlMaster=auto` is defined in `ssh_args` in Ansible [in `ansible.cfg`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#ssh-args):

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s
```

---

The following error is related to SSH connection multiplexing:

> Control socket connect(/tmp): Permission denied
>   ControlSocket /tmp already exists, disabling multiplexing
>   Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed

It tried to create a socket directly at `/tmp`, not inside `/tmp`... Some other parameter defined somewhere for SSH could play role here.

Setting the value of `ControlMaster` to `auto` causes SSH to create a new master connection should the existing one not exist (or have problems, as here?).